# conditional mean of a column based on another column in the same xts object

Tags: r, conditional-statements, xts, mean

I have the following `xts` object = `mydata`:

```
row.names   ret   flag
8/1/2014    10     1
8/4/2014    12     3
8/5/2014    -15    2
8/6/2014    05     1
8/7/2014   -06     2
```

I would like to find the mean of all returns that have a flag =1, flag = 2, flag = 3

This is what I have:

```
 g.rt= matrix(0, nrow = 3)
 for (i in 1:3)
  {
  rt[i]=sapply(X=1:nrow(mydata), FUN=function(x) 
  {mean(mydata[which(mydata$flag == i),1])})
  }
```

Although it works, I get a warning message

```
    "In g.rt[5] = sapply(X = 1:nrow(tprt), FUN = function(x) { :
    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"
```

I am not really sure what implications its going to have. Can you please look at my code and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `ave` or `tapply` might be useful, but I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: Probably just `aggregate(ret ~ flag, mydata, mean)`

Comment: As fas as I can tell, this has nothing to do with `xts` specifically.

Comment: Neal- I have an extremely large data set where "flag" represents and occurance. I want to find mean of returns (ret)over a 10year period for each occurance type i.e. flag = 1,2,3. Although my code does it, it does it in an inefficient way throwing out a warning message - and i am not sure what harm this warning/"potentialy" can mean for my work.